# How to loop a replace function that modifies text depending on each letter's position in the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, loops

I am trying to loop a function that switches a letter with one that is x places along in the alphabet [**i.e** a +5 **=** f, b+5 **=** g etc] but the function misses out some seemingly random letters AND returns undefined in each instance.

Is it because you are not allowed to do maths inside an array parameter or just another of my trademark syntax errors. I tried using a return function but that stops the execution of a loop.

Another awesome SO'er gave me the code I currently am using but I'm not sure what is going wrong to get the undefineds and the missed out letters.

Code found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clarinetking/kLy83oxj/16/)!

```
$('#write').click(function () {
   $('#txt').html(function (i, v) {
     for(x=0;x<j;x++) {
         v = v.replace(alphabet[x], alphabet[x+num]);
         }
         return v;
     });
});
```

Comment: What's `j`?  Also declare your local variables with `var`!!!

Comment: j is just a comparison variable. I would've used i like normal but was afraid it would interfere with an earlier function

Comment: What's a "comparison variable"?  Where does `j` get a value?

Comment: Sorry, that's what I call them on account of me being dumb and all :P it's just a variable that's the same size as alphabet.length but I didn't want to use that as the array is modified before this function is executed

Comment: OK, well you haven't anywhere actually *assigned* `alphabet.length` to the variable `j`.  Another problem is that you're trying to update the "txt" `<textarea>` using the `.html()` function, which is incorrect - you set the value of a `<textarea>` with `.val()`.

Comment: All my syntax problems aside why won't the actual 'function' work? Also, I didn't want to set j to alphabet.length, just 26 :) Thanks for pointing it out though

Edit: Dear GOD that's a lot of rep. Well done :)

Comment: Oh wait, sorry; I thought `#txt` was a `<textarea>`, but it's not. I regret to say that it's kind-of hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: Awfully sorry. I should most likely add comments to my work
http://jsfiddle.net/clarinetking/kLy83oxj/17/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kLy83oxj/18/

Comment: ARE YOU GOD?? Thank you so much :D How does it all work though?? @sabithpocker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alphabet` array will hold the alphabets in real world. 
Then we create a *copy of* alphabets array and store it in `cipher`
We cut `num` alphabets from front and push it to the end of `cipher`, just as you were doing.
*(In the fiddle black letters are `alphabet` array and pink letters are `cipher` array.)*

Now we gets the value of `#txt` as a string in `v`
now for each character `v[x]` in `v` where `x` is index:

- Position of `v[x]` in `alphabets` is found using
  `alphabet.indexOf(v[x])`
- Corresponding ciphertext character is
  found by getting the item in `cipher` array at that position. `cipher[alphabet.indexOf(v[x])]`
- original characters are processed one by one and corresponding `cipher text characters` are calculated and pushed one by one to an array `n` 
  Array `n` is joined to convert it to `String` ready to be used.

---

```
var alphabet, text,num, cipher;
//dont initialize alphabet here if you change it onclick 
//will cause error when doing multiple times

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#solve').click(function () {
        alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
        text = $('#Input').val();
        num = parseInt($('#Number').val(), 10);
        var x = alphabet.slice(0, num);
        cipher = alphabet.slice();//clone array
        cipher.splice(0, num);
        cipher.push.apply(cipher,x);//concatenate two arrays
        $('#CipherSwitch').html(cipher.join(','));
    });
    $('#write').click(function () {
        $('#txt').text(function (i, v) {//html() will process '<br>' as well
            var n = [];
            //other way around is error prone when we have multiple instances of a 
            //char ins string
            for(var x=0;x<v.length;x++) {
                //I have no idea why
                //v[x] = cipher[alphabet.indexOf(v[x])]; is not working??
                n.push(cipher[alphabet.indexOf(v[x])])
            }
            return n.join("");
        });
    });

    $("#append").click(function () {
        $("#txt").append($("#Input").val() + '<br>');
    });
});
```

If you need explanation for anything in your code or my code please ask.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLy83oxj/18)

Comment: What's parsing? I hear about it a lot but never found out what it does?
Why are there so many new variables and what do they do? Thanks again for being such a huge help :)

Comment: Guess its not clear to you will update with explanation once I am back at desk...

Comment: Sorry. I do get most of it and it's incredibly intelligent. It's just all those new variables that are confusing :) sorry to be a pain :/

Comment: @Clarinetking Parsing is like breaking down sentences into constituents in an attempt to translate or understand its meaning. As you read this you are doing kind of pattern recognition, lexical analysis and parsing to understand the sentence. Parsing in Computation generally refers to similar processing of computer languages in an attempt to translate it to another language or low level machine language that can be fed to hardware units. Yeah its hard to explain in a comment... people end up writing big text books trying to explain parsing :)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
    var rewrite = function(i, n) {          
      var a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
      var txt = "";
      var len = function(c) { 
        return a.match(new RegExp(c, "i")).index + n > a.length - 1 
               ? a.match(new RegExp(c, "i")).index + n - (a.length) 
               : a.match(new RegExp(c, "i")).index + n
      };
      // `CipherSwitch`
      var txt = [].slice.call(a.slice(-(a.length -n))
                .concat(a.slice(0, n))).join(",");
      $.each([].slice.call(i), function(k, v) {
        _txt += a.charAt(len(v));
        // `Rewrite` 
        _txt = _txt;
      });

      return [txt, _txt]
    };
```

at `#solve`

```
    $('#solve').click(function () {
        var text = $('#Input').val();
        // cast `num` as `Number`
        var num = Number($('#Number').val());
        $('#CipherSwitch').html(
            rewrite(text, num)[0]
        );
    });
```

at `#write`

```
    $('#write').click(function () {
        var text = $('#Input').val();
        // cast `num` as `Number`
        var num = Number($('#Number').val());
        var _text = $("#txt");
        _text.text(
          rewrite(text !== _text.text() ? _text.text() : text, num)[1]
        );
    });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/eyf09w4q/